# How to create a grid of elements (divs/spans) in perfect squares with their backgrounds set to images

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I've been working on a website that serves as a gallery for fantasy art, an evolving project, and I've currently hit a barricade in where to go from something I can't get to work. I tried Masonry and Wookmark both, and had issues with both, so I'm trying to do something else. I'm wanting to spawn in either divs or spans (I'm not sure which to use) within `grid` with the class identifier `images` and set their backgrounds to specific image sources that "cover", centered, so I basically have a grid of square windows into these images and when clicked, they bring up a lightbox (which I've succesfully created). Right now I've managed to get the images to show but the containers are smooshed down and have no padding left or right.

Truth be told, I have no idea what to do with the relative/absolute positioning and inline/block display parameters, and I feel this is where I'm going wrong but I don't know really what these things entail.

Segment of the HTML:

```
<div id="grid" class="grid"></div>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  z-index:2;
  display: inline-block;
}

.images {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  z-index:2;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var mix = shuffle(Object.keys(backInfo));                 


function unlockImages () {      
  setTimeout(function () {          
    if (mix !== undefined) { 
      var input = mix.shift();
      var entry = backInfo[input];
      var elem = document.createElement("div");
      elem.setAttribute("class", "images");
      elem.setAttribute("id", input);
      elem.setAttribute("title", entry.caption);
      elem.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:changeImage(" + input + ");");
      document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(elem);
      document.getElementById(input).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + entry.image + ")";
      $("#" + input).fadeTo(0,0);
      $("#" + input).fadeTo(20000,1);
      unlockImages();
    }
  }, 0)
}
```

And a live preview of what's going on at the moment: http://www.dreamquest.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are describing is css.  I played with your css a little and came up with this:

```
.grid {
  z-index:2;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1500px;
}

.images {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  z-index:2;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Some things to note with your css:

1. when you are setting a percentage width x height, your parent container has to have a value.  Since you didn't set a height value in the .grid class your images get squished because it is taking 25% of 0 height.
2. background-attachment: fixed; forces your picture not to auto resize, which i am assuming you want
3. you were using padding that is why you are not getting the spacing between images.  Padding is for the interior of the element.  If you want space between elements then you need to use margin, which I have used in the above css.  hth

Comment: Definitely getting somewhere with this answer. Thank you. I've got the margin issue fixed now and even got the images to get to the right size I believe, I just have to figure out how to make them stop being in a single column and get them into rows.

Comment: You will need to play around a little with the css.  You have width and height as 100% now.  If you reduce it to 20% then inline-block will automatically arrange it into rows.

Comment: In case you didn't know, the easiest way to play with css is to use chromes' developer console accessible by right clicking the page and click on inspect.  Then on the right panel you can play with the styles.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to create dynamic grid and populate images for each box. Use below code to achieve it.

1. create container div with id "wrapper".
2. Add Javascript function and called it where ever you want.

   function DrawGrid() {

   ```
      var  rows = 2;
      var  columns = 2;

       $("#wrapper").empty();

       for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

           var $row = $("<div />", {
               class: 'row'
           });

           //add columns to the the temp row object
           for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {



               var $square = $("<div />", {
                   class: 'square' 
               });

               //Set your imageHere
               $square.append("<img></img>");


               $row.append($square.clone());
           }


           $("#wrapper").append($row.clone());
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: That looks really cool and that might work somehow, I'm going to try to implement it mayhaps, but it may take me some time because I'm not sure what exactly it's doing/saying, it's somewhat complex to me, and I assume it's using jQuery? I'd rather have some minor alteration to my existing code in any case if possible, so I can make changes to it later and not be lost. I'll take your answer into consideration but hopefully someone else can offer some insight into the positioning/display issues I'm running into.

Comment: Yes you can modify it according to your requirement. It's dynamic and simple hope will solve your issues.